# PostgreSQL: How to get a weekly average over a year including 'gap' weeks per animal from years of data?

Tags: postgresql, date

I have a lot of occurrences from different animals (see below) from many many years.

I am trying to figure out how to get the average occurrence per week on a year scale per animal. I eventually want to use the data to create a graph that shows when you can see the animal during the year.

I came up with the following sql but I got stuck as it does not fill the 'gap' weeks as I hoped. I am almost there I feel, but...

1. The commented out part was a fiddle to see if I could get the yearly
   average instead of the total of ALL years
2. I am missing the 'gap' weeks from my generate_series. Now they are generated over all animals. I miss some understanding here.

[My fiddle is here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/4e2b1/15)

(There is also a bias in the data so that dec-31 and jan-1 should be skipped as only the year was known and data had to be entered as 'date')

```sql
    --WITH occurrence as (
    SELECT name, w.week, count(total) as total
    FROM  ( SELECT generate_series(1,53,1) ) w(week)
    LEFT JOIN occurrence i ON w.week = cast(date_part('week',i.from_date) as integer)
    AND TO_CHAR(from_date :: DATE, 'dd/mm') NOT IN ('31/12','01/01')
    AND name IS NOT NULL
    GROUP  BY name,w.week
    ORDER  BY name,w.week;
    --)
    --SELECT o.week, ROUND(AVG(o.total))
    --FROM occurrence o
    --GROUP BY o.week
```

Will give me the following shortened result:

```
name    week    total
bird    15      2
bird    16      2
...
bird    30      1
bird    38      1
cat     11      1
cat     14      1
...
cat     30      4
dog     14      1
dog     15      2
...
dog     33      1
dog     38      1
(null)  1       0
...
(null)  53      0
```

the test sql:

```sql
CREATE TABLE occurrence (name text,total int,from_date date);
INSERT INTO occurrence (name,total,from_date) VALUES
('cat',1,'1800-01-01'),
('bird',1,'1846-06-13'),
('dog',1,'1865-05-24'),
('dog',11,'1869-05-02'),
('dog',1,'1869-05-06'),
('dog',1,'1869-05-12'),
('cat',1,'1870-01-01'),
('dog',2,'1872-06-06'),
('dog',1,'1876-04-24'),
('dog',1,'1882-05-01'),
('dog',1,'1883-04-30'),
('dog',1,'1884-05-11'),
('cat',1,'1884-06-22'),
('dog',1,'1885-04-23'),
('cat',1,'1885-07-08'),
('cat',1,'1885-07-10'),
('dog',1,'1890-05-25'),
('dog',1,'1894-05-18'),
('bird',1,'1894-06-16'),
('bird',1,'1894-06-16'),
('cat',1,'1895-05-14'),
('dog',1,'1896-06-01'),
('dog',1,'1900-05-24'),
('dog',1,'1903-05-27'),
('cat',1,'1905-03-14'),
('bird',3,'1905-04-23'),
('dog',1,'1905-05-19'),
('dog',1,'1905-05-19'),
('dog',1,'1905-05-19'),
('dog',3,'1905-06-12'),
('cat',1,'1905-06-27'),
('dog',1,'1905-06-29'),
('bird',1,'1906-05-15'),
('bird',1,'1906-05-15'),
('bird',1,'1906-05-15'),
('bird',1,'1907-05-12'),
('bird',1,'1907-05-12'),
('bird',1,'1907-05-12'),
('bird',1,'1909-06-21'),
('bird',1,'1909-06-21'),
('bird',3,'1910-05-14'),
('bird',4,'1910-05-21'),
('bird',1,'1910-05-21'),
('dog',3,'1910-05-22'),
('dog',1,'1910-05-27'),
('dog',1,'1910-05-27'),
('dog',1,'1910-05-27'),
('dog',1,'1912-05-28'),
('dog',1,'1912-06-11'),
('dog',1,'1913-05-12'),
('dog',1,'1913-05-12'),
('bird',2,'1913-05-14'),
('bird',2,'1913-05-14'),
('dog',1,'1914-01-01'),
('cat',3,'1914-07-03'),
('cat',1,'1914-07-06'),
('cat',1,'1916-05-28'),
('dog',1,'1916-05-29'),
('dog',1,'1916-05-29'),
('dog',1,'1916-05-29'),
('cat',1,'1916-06-14'),
('bird',1,'1916-06-18'),
('dog',1,'1917-05-01'),
('dog',1,'1917-05-25'),
('dog',1,'1918-01-01'),
('dog',3,'1918-05-20'),
('dog',1,'1919-05-24'),
('dog',1,'1919-05-25'),
('dog',2,'1919-05-29'),
('bird',1,'1919-06-09'),
('bird',1,'1919-06-09'),
('dog',2,'1920-05-20'),
('bird',1,'1920-05-29'),
('bird',1,'1920-05-29'),
('dog',1,'1921-05-05'),
('dog',1,'1921-05-09'),
('dog',1,'1922-05-08'),
('cat',1,'1922-06-15'),
('dog',1,'1922-07-02'),
('dog',1,'1923-04-04'),
('dog',1,'1923-05-29'),
('bird',1,'1923-06-25'),
('dog',1,'1924-01-01'),
('dog',1,'1924-05-17'),
('bird',1,'1925-04-08'),
('bird',1,'1925-04-08'),
('bird',1,'1926-06-28'),
('bird',2,'1927-05-21'),
('bird',2,'1927-05-21'),
('bird',1,'1927-05-26'),
('dog',1,'1928-06-12'),
('cat',1,'1931-05-23'),
('dog',1,'1932-05-16'),
('bird',2,'1932-06-15'),
('bird',1,'1932-06-19'),
('bird',3,'1932-06-19'),
('bird',1,'1933-07-22'),
('cat',1,'1934-06-02'),
('bird',1,'1934-06-04'),
('bird',1,'1934-06-05'),
('bird',1,'1934-06-08'),
('bird',1,'1934-06-09'),
('cat',1,'1934-06-10'),
('bird',1,'1934-06-13'),
('bird',1,'1937-05-29'),
('cat',1,'1937-06-07'),
('bird',1,'1938-07-03'),
('cat',1,'1938-07-07'),
('dog',1,'1939-01-01'),
('dog',3,'1939-05-09'),
('dog',1,'1939-05-21'),
('dog',1,'1939-05-23'),
('dog',1,'1939-05-29'),
('cat',1,'1939-06-11'),
('bird',1,'1939-06-11'),
('dog',2,'1940-05-03'),
('dog',3,'1940-05-03'),
('dog',1,'1941-05-16'),
('cat',1,'1942-07-12'),
('cat',1,'1942-07-13'),
('dog',1,'1943-04-26'),
('dog',1,'1943-05-09'),
('bird',1,'1943-05-13'),
('dog',1,'1944-05-06'),
('dog',1,'1944-05-06'),
('cat',1,'1945-07-02'),
('dog',1,'1945-07-03'),
('dog',1,'1946-04-12'),
('dog',1,'1946-05-08'),
('bird',1,'1946-05-12'),
('bird',1,'1946-05-12'),
('bird',2,'1946-05-12'),
('bird',1,'1946-07-25'),
('bird',1,'1947-06-01'),
('cat',1,'1947-06-19'),
('bird',1,'1949-04-29'),
('dog',1,'1949-05-04'),
('bird',1,'1949-05-15'),
('bird',1,'1949-06-05'),
('cat',2,'1949-07-16'),
('bird',3,'1950-04-17'),
('cat',1,'1950-06-24'),
('dog',1,'1951-05-08'),
('bird',1,'1956-05-27'),
('cat',1,'1957-06-07'),
('dog',1,'1958-01-01'),
('bird',1,'1958-06-25'),
('bird',1,'1958-07-11'),
('cat',1,'1958-07-20'),
('bird',15,'1960-05-22'),
('bird',1,'1960-05-22'),
('dog',1,'1960-05-29'),
('dog',1,'1960-06-11'),
('cat',2,'1960-06-26'),
('dog',0,'1960-09-22'),
('dog',1,'1961-04-12'),
('cat',1,'1961-06-22'),
('bird',1,'1961-07-16'),
('cat',1,'1962-06-29'),
('cat',2,'1962-07-06'),
('bird',1,'1963-05-23'),
('bird',1,'1963-06-21'),
('bird',1,'1963-06-25'),
('dog',2,'1963-07-17'),
('dog',0,'1963-07-17'),
('cat',1,'1964-04-02'),
('bird',1,'1964-05-17'),
('dog',1,'1964-05-26'),
('bird',1,'1964-06-05'),
('bird',1,'1964-06-08'),
('bird',1,'1964-06-15'),
('cat',1,'1964-06-26'),
('bird',1,'1964-07-01'),
('cat',1,'1964-07-09'),
('bird',1,'1965-06-11'),
('bird',1,'1965-07-11'),
('dog',1,'1966-05-16'),
('cat',1,'1966-06-18'),
('cat',1,'1966-07-01'),
('dog',0,'1966-08-08'),
('dog',0,'1966-08-18'),
('dog',1,'1967-01-01'),
('dog',1,'1967-05-05'),
('bird',1,'1967-05-07'),
('dog',1,'1967-05-08'),
('bird',1,'1967-05-30'),
('bird',1,'1967-06-18'),
('bird',1,'1967-06-25'),
('dog',1,'1967-06-27'),
('bird',1,'1967-06-28'),
('cat',1,'1967-07-16'),
('cat',1,'1967-07-16'),
('dog',1,'1968-04-24'),
('bird',1,'1968-05-16'),
('bird',1,'1968-05-23'),
('bird',1,'1968-05-25'),
('dog',2,'1968-05-30'),
('cat',1,'1968-06-19'),
('dog',1,'1969-05-08'),
('dog',2,'1969-05-14'),
('bird',1,'1969-06-07'),
('bird',1,'1969-06-08'),
('bird',1,'1969-06-08'),
('bird',3,'1969-06-08'),
('bird',2,'1969-06-11'),
('bird',1,'1969-06-11'),
('bird',1,'1969-06-29'),
('bird',1,'1969-06-29'),
('cat',1,'1969-07-21'),
('cat',1,'1969-07-21'),
('bird',3,'1970-05-24'),
('bird',3,'1970-05-24'),
('bird',2,'1970-06-07'),
('bird',2,'1970-06-13'),
('bird',1,'1970-06-24'),
('bird',0,'1970-09-16'),
('dog',1,'1971-04-22'),
('dog',1,'1971-05-04'),
('dog',1,'1971-05-05'),
('dog',1,'1971-05-05'),
('dog',1,'1971-05-06'),
('bird',1,'1972-05-06'),
('bird',5,'1972-05-07'),
('cat',1,'1972-05-19'),
('bird',1,'1972-05-19'),
('bird',1,'1972-05-20'),
('dog',1,'1972-05-24'),
('cat',1,'1972-07-29'),
('bird',1,'1973-05-05'),
('bird',1,'1973-05-06'),
('dog',2,'1973-05-17'),
('bird',1,'1973-05-18'),
('dog',1,'1973-05-21'),
('dog',1,'1973-05-28'),
('cat',1,'1973-06-24'),
('bird',4,'1974-05-16'),
('dog',1,'1974-05-23'),
('dog',4,'1974-05-24'),
('cat',1,'1974-06-16'),
('cat',3,'1974-06-16'),
('bird',1,'1974-07-04'),
('cat',1,'1975-05-25'),
('cat',2,'1975-05-25'),
('cat',1,'1975-06-23'),
('cat',1,'1975-06-23'),
('cat',1,'1975-07-02'),
('bird',2,'1975-07-08'),
('bird',12,'1976-05-23'),
('bird',12,'1976-05-23'),
('bird',4,'1976-05-30'),
('bird',4,'1976-05-30'),
('cat',1,'1976-07-20'),
('dog',1,'1977-01-01'),
('dog',1,'1977-04-26'),
('cat',1,'1977-05-09'),
('bird',3,'1977-06-06'),
('bird',7,'1977-06-06'),
('bird',3,'1977-06-07'),
('bird',1,'1977-06-07'),
('bird',6,'1977-06-07'),
('bird',1,'1977-06-09'),
('cat',2,'1977-06-20'),
('cat',3,'1977-06-20'),
('cat',2,'1977-06-22'),
('cat',1,'1977-06-22'),
('cat',1,'1977-06-24'),
('cat',1,'1977-06-24'),
('cat',1,'1977-07-21'),
('bird',1,'1978-05-18'),
('bird',4,'1978-05-18'),
('dog',1,'1978-05-27'),
('cat',1,'1978-05-28'),
('cat',1,'1978-05-28'),
('dog',1,'1978-05-30'),
('cat',2,'1978-05-30'),
('dog',1,'1978-05-31'),
('dog',3,'1978-06-01'),
('bird',1,'1978-06-15'),
('cat',1,'1978-06-15'),
('cat',4,'1978-06-15'),
('bird',1,'1978-06-22'),
('cat',2,'1978-06-22'),
('cat',2,'1978-06-23'),
('cat',10,'1978-06-24'),
('cat',1,'1978-07-06'),
('cat',1,'1978-07-06'),
('cat',1,'1978-07-09'),
('cat',1,'1978-07-09');
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you had a scaffoold for the week numbers, that was a good start, but you also need a scaffold for the names, then you can left join both scaffolds and get a result that contains zeroes.

```
SELECT b.name, w.week, count(total) as total
FROM  generate_series(1,53,1) w(week)
CROSS JOIN ( values ('cat'),('dog'),('bird') ) b(name) 
LEFT JOIN occurrence i ON w.week = cast(date_part('week',i.from_date) as integer)
   AND TO_CHAR(from_date :: DATE, 'dd/mm') NOT IN ('31/12','01/01')
   AND i.name = b.name 
GROUP  BY b.name,w.week
ORDER  BY b.name,w.week;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!17/c96d0/5

Here I used inline values for `b` but if you have a table with all the names you could use that instead.
or you could use `(select distinct name from occurrence) as b`

Comment: Thank you @Jasen! I indeed had to use the select distinct. I must admit I still do not see how this is working but it does. (I am a visual person)

Comment: I changed the COUNT(total) into AVG(total) as this is what I was looking for. Somehow i get NULL value for the 'empty' weeks.

Comment: Any idea how this is possible? I ended up with CAST(ROUND(COUNT(total)) as INTEGER) at the end so I get back 0's

Comment: Note that `FROM  ( SELECT generate_series(1,53,1) ) w(week)` can be simplified to `FROM generate_series(1,53,1) w(week)`